# Move a list of files from multiple locations to another

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a powershell script which moves a list files from a list to a destination folder.

`C:\list.txt` contains the full path of every file, e.g. `C:\testfolder\test.jpg`, the file can have from 10 paths to 1000.

I wrote the following code so far. But using `$search_folder` means it is only looking in 1 folder, but I want it to look at the paths in `list.txt`.

I can't seem to find out how to make it look for path of the files from my `list.txt`.

```
$file_list = Get-Content C:\list.txt
$search_folder = "C:\test1"
$destination_folder = "C:\test2"

foreach ($file in $file_list) {
    $file_to_move = Get-ChildItem -Path $search_folder -Filter $file -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force | % { $_.FullName}
    if ($file_to_move) {
        Move-Item $file_to_move $destination_folder
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, if your files to be moved (the ones written in `list.txt`) come from different drives, why do you search for them in `$search_folder`? Secondly, assuming you don't care the tree structure of the target folder, if `list.txt` contains the absolute path to the files to be moved, why don't you feed directly the 1st argument of `Move-Item` with those paths?

Answer (score 1):

`Move-Item` will take an array of strings for `Path`, so you can directly use `$file_list` from `Get-Content`:

```
$file_list = Get-Content C:\list.txt
$destination_folder = C:\test2

Move-Item -Path $file_list -Destination $destination_folder
```

...which can actually be shortened to a oneliner:

```
Move-Item -Path (Get-Content C:\folder\list.txt) -Destination C:\test2
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `list.txt` file contains full paths, you don't really need to search the file in a folder to determine whether that file exists.

You only need to test the full path, and then move it to the destination:

```
$file_list = Get-Content C:\list.txt
$destination_folder = "C:\test2"

ForEach ($file in $file_list) {
    If (Test-Path $file) {
        Move-Item $file $destination_folder
    }
}
```